# How can I stop pygame looping though a dictionary uncontrollably?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make my first GUI quiz game. But for some reason when I run the code to loop through the questions, it does it too fast and doesn't wait for the user to choose one on the choices before moving onto the next question.

The number of iterations are supposed to be variable as the user should be able to choose the number of questions, so I can't make a function for each questions and instead am trying to loop though a dictionary and displaying it on the screen. But ran onto more problems. Is there any way for the program to wait until the user chooses one of the choices before moving onto the next question.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from gui import Button, FlagButton
from os import path
from q_gen import generate_question
import sys

pygame.init()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1000, 600
win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("World game")

font_path = path.join("fonts", "PartyConfetti.ttf")

small_font = pygame.font.Font(font_path, 50)

centre = ((win.get_width())//2, (win.get_height())//2)

WHITE =        (255, 255, 255)
BLACK =        (  0,   0,   0)
PASTEL_BLUE =  (189, 242, 255)

button_img = pygame.image.load(path.join("assets", "button.png"))
button_img = pygame.transform.scale(button_img, (300, 100))
arrow = pygame.image.load(path.join("assets", "arrow.png"))
arrow = pygame.transform.scale(arrow, (50, 50))
up = pygame.transform.rotate(arrow, 90)
down = pygame.transform.rotate(arrow, 270)

def game():
    questions = generate_question("capital", 5, 1)
    pressed = False
    running = True
    while running:
        
        for q in questions:
            win.fill(PASTEL_BLUE)

            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

            title = small_font.render(f"{q}. {questions[q][0]}", True, "black")
            title_rect = title.get_rect(center=(centre[0], centre[1]-200))
            win.blit(title, title_rect)

            choice1 = Button(win, button_img, (300, 500), "CHOICE")
            choice1.changeColor(mouse_pos)
            choice1.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if choice1.checkForInput(mouse_pos):
                        pressed = True
                        break
            pygame.display.update()
            if pressed:
                continue
            
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit(0)
```

The question generator and class for the button, if needed, is below.

```
from info import info # Large dictionary containing info of countries
from random import choice, randint

modes = ("capital", "flag", "currency")

def generate_question(mode, q_no, difficulty):
    questions = {}
    new_mode = mode
    for i in range(1, q_no+1):
        reverse = choice((True, False))
        country = choice(list(info.keys()))
        choices = []
        if mode == "mixed":
            new_mode = choice(modes)
        if new_mode != "flag":
            query = info[country][new_mode]
            if reverse:
                question = f"Which country is {query} the {new_mode} of?"
                answer = country
                while len(choices)<=(difficulty-1)*2:
                    rand_choice = choice(list(info.keys()))
                    if rand_choice != answer and rand_choice not in choices:
                        choices.append(rand_choice)
            else:
                question = f"What is the {new_mode} of {country}?"
                answer = query
                while len(choices)<=(difficulty-1)*2:
                    rand_country = choice(list(info.keys()))
                    rand_choice = info[rand_country][new_mode]
                    if rand_choice != answer and rand_choice not in choices:
                        choices.append(rand_choice)
            choices.insert(randint(0, len(choices)), answer)
            questions[i] = (question, country, new_mode, answer, choices)
        else:
            question = f"Which one is the flag of {country}?"
            answer = f"{country}.png"
    return questions
```

```
import os
import pygame

pygame.init()

class Button():
    def __init__(self, screen, image, pos, text_input, font=os.path.join("fonts", "PartyConfetti.ttf"), text_size=50):
        self.screen = screen
        self.image = image
        self.x_pos = pos[0]
        self.y_pos = pos[1]
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(font, text_size)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(self.x_pos, self.y_pos))
        self.text_input = text_input
        self.text = self.font.render(self.text_input, True, "black")
        self.text_rect = self.text.get_rect(center=(self.x_pos, self.y_pos))

    def update(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.text, self.text_rect)

    def checkForInput(self, position):
        if position[0] in range(self.rect.left, self.rect.right) and position[1] in range(self.rect.top, self.rect.bottom):
            return True
        return False

    def changeColor(self, position):
        if position[0] in range(self.rect.left, self.rect.right) and position[1] in range(self.rect.top, self.rect.bottom):
            self.text = self.font.render(self.text_input, True, "white")
        else:
            self.text = self.font.render(self.text_input, True, "black")

class FlagButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, screen, image, pos, text_input, flag_image, font=os.path.join("fonts", "PartyConfetti.ttf"), text_size=50):
        super().__init__(screen, image, pos, text_input, font, text_size)
        self.flag_image = flag_image
        self.flag_image_rect = self.flag_image.get_rect(center=(self.x_pos, self.y_pos))
    def update(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.flag_image, self.flag_image_rect)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```py
if pressed:
    continue
```

[`continue` does not do what you think it does](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_continue.asp), it only skips the rest of the current iteration and continues with the loop.

Instead, you could use a while loop to keep looping over the click check until a button is pressed.

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from gui import Button, FlagButton
from os import path
from q_gen import generate_question
import sys

pygame.init()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1000, 600
win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("World game")

font_path = path.join("fonts", "PartyConfetti.ttf")

small_font = pygame.font.Font(font_path, 50)

centre = ((win.get_width())//2, (win.get_height())//2)

WHITE =        (255, 255, 255)
BLACK =        (  0,   0,   0)
PASTEL_BLUE =  (189, 242, 255)

button_img = pygame.image.load(path.join("assets", "button.png"))
button_img = pygame.transform.scale(button_img, (300, 100))
arrow = pygame.image.load(path.join("assets", "arrow.png"))
arrow = pygame.transform.scale(arrow, (50, 50))
up = pygame.transform.rotate(arrow, 90)
down = pygame.transform.rotate(arrow, 270)

def game():
    questions = generate_question("capital", 5, 1)
    pressed = False
    running = True

    while running:
        for q in questions:
            win.fill(PASTEL_BLUE)

            title = small_font.render(f"{q}. {questions[q][0]}", True, "black")
            title_rect = title.get_rect(center=(centre[0], centre[1]-200))
            win.blit(title, title_rect)

            choice1 = Button(win, button_img, (300, 500), "CHOICE")

            while not pressed and running:
                mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

                choice1.changeColor(mouse_pos)
                choice1.update()

                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        running = False
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        if choice1.checkForInput(mouse_pos):
                            pressed = True
                pygame.display.update()

            if not running:
                break
            
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit(0)
```

There are probably still some problems with this code but hopefully this helps fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, it worked exactly as I wanted

Comment: No problem, good luck!